# Collecting data in recursion function in C

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I am writing an huffman algorithm and I got problem with a collecting data in recursion function. It means I have a recursion function which generates codes from tree, but I would like to have them in array (this allow me processing data later). I wrote the function

```
void save_code(HuffNode** array, int pos, HuffNode *node, char * table, int depth)
{
  if(node->left == NULL){
    printf("%d - %c > ", pos, node->sign);

    array[pos]->sign = node->sign;
    strcpy(array[pos]->code, table);

    puts(table);
    // save to global table
  }
  else {
    table[depth] = '0';
    save_code(array, pos + 1, node->left, table, depth + 1);
    table[depth] = '1';
    save_code(array, pos + 1 , node->right, table, depth + 1);
  }
}
```

The biggest problem I have with variable pos, I thought if I can increment the pos variable (like in loop for),so I would be able to save it in variable array at position pos. The whole program is here: https://github.com/mtczerwinski/algorithms/blob/master/huffman/huffman.c

Edit:
I ask myself if global variable can solve a problem - after a few moments of coding - the answer is positive.

```
int pos = 0; // global variable
void save_code(HuffNode** array, HuffNode *node, char * table, int depth) {
  if(node->left == NULL){
    array[pos]->sign = node->sign;
    strcpy(array[pos]->code, table);
    pos++;
  }
  else {
    table[depth] = '0';
    save_code(array , node->left, table, depth + 1);
    table[depth] = '1';
    save_code(array, node->right, table, depth + 1);
  }
}
```

I would like to ask how to collect data in recursion function between calls. What are other ways to solve problem like this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pass it by pointer:**

```
void save_code(..., int *pos)
{
  // ...
  // use and modify (*pos) as you desire
  // ...
  save_code(..., pos);
  // ...
}
```

This is a good approach, except that it doesn't look too pretty - you have an additional parameter for each recursive call and you have to use `*pos` instead of `pos`.

**Pass and return it:**

```
int save_code(..., int pos)
{
  // ...
  // use and modify pos as you desire
  // ...
  pos = save_code(..., pos);
  // ...
  return pos;
}
```

I wouldn't really recommend this (at least not above pass by pointer) as you'd return and pass a value, which seems unnecessary, since you only need to do one of those.

You also can't use this approach with multiple values, but it's easy to fix by using a `struct`, although if the function already returns something, this gets quite a bit messier.

**And, for completeness, global variable:**

```
int pos = 0; // global variable
void save_code(...)
{
  // ...
  // use and modify pos as you desire
  // ...
  save_code(...);
  // ...
}
```

This has the disadvantage of having a `pos` variable floating around in global scope, but this could, in many cases, fairly easily be fixed by making it `static` so it's limited to one file, or, in the OOP world (e.g. in C++), one could hide this as a private class member.

Using a global variable would be a problem with multi-threading (i.e. multiple calls to the function executing at the same time).

---

I chose to favour brevity above completeness with regard to my code samples - I hope they're readable enough.